# Cakephp 2.5 pass data to controller action

Tags: cakephp-2.3

I am using CakePhp 2.5 and i am into a view that have the $data array,

This is the result of a search form and i can var_dump and see is there.

How can i pass this same $data array to an action of the same controller that show the output in PDF format?  ?

I try :

```
echo $this->Html->Link("PDF", array('controller' => 'Verify',
                                     'action'=> 'resultsPdf', $data),);
```

I just get : `array (size=0) empty`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass an array as an argument to a controller function like that.  One way around that would be to encode the array as a json string, and then decode in the controller action.

```
$encoded = json_encode($data);
echo $this->Html->Link(
    "PDF", 
    array(
        'controller' => 'Verify',
        'action'=> 'resultsPdf',
        $encoded
    )
);
```

Controller:

```
function resultsPdf($data) {
    $data = json_decode($data);
}
```

Another approach would be through named parameters:

```
$encoded = json_encode($data);
echo $this->Html->Link(
    "PDF", 
    array(
        'controller' => 'Verify',
        'action'=> 'resultsPdf',
        'encoded' => $encoded
    )
);
```

Controller:

```
function resultsPdf() {
    $data = json_decode($this->params['named']['encoded']);
}
```

Comment: just try, i see the json string as argument but the argument is not received by resultsPdf($data) : Missing argument 1 for VerifyController::resultsPdf()

Comment: can i just pass the conditions array or the paginate array to the resultPdf action so i can query again ?

Comment: The problem is that you can't pass an array as a url parameter, so you can't pass the conditions or paginate array to the resultPdf action in that way.  I've added another approach to my answer which might help.

Comment: great!  i can see the params in the action  now.

Comment: can i just get the data array from one controller method to another ? as asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39470235/cakephp-2-5-sharing-result-dataset-between-controllers-methods