# Cakephp 2. 5 Sharing result dataset between controllers methods

Tags: cakephp

I am using CakePHp 2.5 and i do generate `$data` array from the consult controller method, as a database results from a query,  using set: `$this->set('data', $services);` i can have it available at `list.ctp` file as `$data` array.

How can i share the same dataset result to another method to generate PDF, having a link or a form into `list.ctp`?

I try this but get null for `$this->data`

```
public function pdfResults( ){
   var_dump($this->data);
```

Comment: store results to session

Comment: thank you @Salines it works,